# send notifications to sub category of consumers dynamically using django channels

Tags: django-channels

I am using **django channel** for notifying consumers asynchronously but there exist a problem. how can I send notification just to a sub set of registered consumers through querying database first and then sending notification to this subset?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your question? by querying the db first to fetch the users and then sending the notification. You may want to specify the particular problem you have with the approach you mentioned because it's not yet clear

Comment: @Ken4scholars the problem is that when different users register in special groups, they will be in that group and the notification sent to them, but we want a way to send notification online and dynamic based on online query to a group which members are not the same as the first group that beforehand was created. thanks

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean but what I do is that I create a group for each user in my DB and upon any channel connection from the user I increment his connections_number which is stored in the DB. I decrement it when any of his connections are disconnected. In that case I'm able to send messages to all devices that the user is connected with and also know when he's online or offline. Online when connections_number is > 0 and offline otherwise